# Display Map in fragment after button click

Tags: android, google-maps, android-fragments

I am trying to use Google Map in an Android project. The details of a person will be displayed in row along with a button on clicking which the location will be shown using Latitude and longitude saved against that person. I am using fragment for display purpose.

activity_show_map.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<fragment xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/map"
android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.example.dioglgt.myapplication.ClinicFragment" />
```

The corresponding ClinicFragment java class is given below:

```
public class ClinicFragment extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback {

private GoogleMap mMap;
public static ClinicFragment newInstance() {
    ClinicFragment fragment = new ClinicFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_show_map, null, false);

    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) this.getChildFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

    return view;
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;

    LatLng testLocation = new LatLng(93.972, 26.515);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(testLocation).title("Marker in Sydney"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(testLocation));
}
}
```

Now to trigger map display on button click, I have use the code below:

```
  public void onShowLocationClick(View view) {
    FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
    transaction.add(R.id.map,new ClinicFragment());
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
}
```

But I am getting the error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f0e0087 (com.example.dioglgt.myapplication:id/map) for fragment ClinicFragment{9dd7da #0 id=0x7f0e0087}
```

Please guide in this regard.

Comment: The first argument in `transaction.add()` is the ID for the `ViewGroup` that the `Fragment` will go into, not its own ID.

Comment: Try to use this code `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_show_map, container, false);` in the `onCreateView()` method in the `ClinicFragment` fragment.

Comment: Why the down vote? Doesn't it show any effort on my part, is it unclear or is it not useful ? I have posted the question here after putting in lots of effort and time. Maybe down voting the question shows how knowledgeable you are.

Comment: I can't really speak for others, but we get this question multiple times a week - the wrong ID for a `FragmentTransaction`. Perhaps you were downvoted for lack of research, which is one of the reasons listed if you hover over the downvote arrow.

Comment: But isn't it possible that I couldn't grasp a point despite research. If one were to understand everything from doing research in web itself, there won't be need to approach a forum like Stack Overflow.

Comment: Of course. You can't be expected to know or understand everything, obviously, but you need to show us what you've researched and tested, not just for the sake of doing it, but to help us diagnose the issue, and to not waste our time repeating things you've already read or attempted. Honestly, your question really doesn't show any effort on your part to solve this. It's just your code, and the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have to use this

```
 public void onShowLocationClick(View view) {
        FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(android.R.id.content,new ClinicFragment());
        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
        transaction.commit();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add ClinicFragment on fragment with id map with is inside activity_show_map which is set to Clinic fragment. Try to use frameLayout and replace that frameLayout with your fragment on button click link below:

```
Fragmentmanager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.fragment_container, new ClinicFragment()).commit();
```

In above code `fragment_container` is a FrameLayout which will be replaced with you're `ClinicFragment`;